# program delete on a table with foreign key constraints and delete NO ACTION

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, get

So I have five tables: job , category, job_category, client and job_client. job_client and job_category have an FK of job_id which references job table. Those FK's are set to ON DELETE NO ACTION. What I'm trying to figure out is whats a good way to program this so that I can click a button to delete a job from the job table, but it automatically goes and delete its references in the job_category and job_client first, then delete the job. I'm using MySQL and PHP. Thanks.

Comment: so you want child cascading deletes?

Comment: So I must use cascading deletes for this, there isn't a way to it that effect with DELETE NO ACTION?

Comment: You can delete manually

Comment: I was trying to come up with some sort of solution where when I say delete a job the logic knows to go and delete references in other tables first then come back and delete the job.

Comment: Well as it is such a common use case, they baked it into InnoDB with FK's and cascading deletes to spare the dev of doing such a thing. Which also encourages having FK's in the first place and Referential Integrity

Comment: so you're saying cascading deletes is the way to go for what i'm trying to do, I can change the delete type after the table is created right. Will check out using cascade deletes

Answer (score 1):

Those FK's are set to ON DELETE NO ACTION.

```
Set all to ON DELETE  CASCADE.
```

IT will delete all foreign keys from any tables.

More info:

In outside world, deletion of record is not advisable, use tagged deleted 1 or 0 instead.

Comment: tagged deleted? how does that work? and how would I apply that to my situation? I have some stuff on the front end that show be removed when I remove a job from job table.

Comment: I think he means do a soft delete. Mark it, filter.

Comment: @Drew soft delete, hhmmm, never encountered this before will do some research.

Comment: Well it is like when you delete your question or answer with the delete button thingie. That is a soft delete. `isActive int not null` ... 1 show it. 0 don't

Comment: oh jus some boolean swith thing, cool so its still in the db, ok got it

Comment: @Patrick is problem solved?

Comment: @reds nope not yet reading up on cascading deletes and best practices for deleting from mysql

Comment: best practice do not delete a record from db, use the above field as tagging 0 or 1. 1 means deleted 0 means not deleted. by default use this field value to 0

Comment: @reds would you recommend creating a separate table for deleted records (soft delete) and if so, could you give tips on implementing this also, if I use soft delete how do I manage those foreign key relationships to tag them as deleted also

Comment: All foreign keys will stay and depends on deteled tag if 0 or 1. you can create a separate table on it its up to you, like primarykeyid, deleted for a separate table or add another column into primary table called deleted int(1) default 0. This all record depends on deleted field if 0 or 1.

Comment: As a result all records will stay and it all depends on your query in condition where deleted = 0